# Refresh/ Reset essential .conf files

Tags: dpkg

I noticed I have a very faulty `rc.local` and would like to have the package releasers version right now, and not when it has to upgrade. Can someone hint me to the options, or the full command it needs to renew/reset these essential files?

Comment: The default `rc.local` is just a bunch of comments with `exit 0` at the end.

Answer (score 0):

Per default, there is nothing in `/etc/init.d/rc.local`, only a she-bang and a `exit 0`, which is very important.

```
 printf '#!/bin/sh -e\nexit 0\n' | sudo tee /etc/rc.local
```

Comment: Woah! That's `/etc/rc.local`, *not* `/etc/init.d/rc.local`.